# AZ Directory posts directory index

Tags: categories, archives

I would like to create an A to Z index of posts in a certain category. This must include a linkable directory of letters ABCDEF .... etc and a list of articles ordered by title grouped by letter.

for example

```
A 
A first article 
A second article

B 
B first article
B Second aericle 

C
```

when some one clicks on the index (ABCDE .....)  link him to the letter group....

Any ideas?

Comment: Downvoted, due to the scope of this question. It is at least two (if not more) questions in one, in a "*do-work-for-me*" format: query posts by category, create letter index, sort posts by first letter.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy if all posts are shown on the same page, then you can do:

```
$AZposts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'     => -1,
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'orderby'         => 'title',
    'order'           => 'ASC',
    'category'    => $cat
));

$current = "";
$nav = "";
$postlist = "";
foreach($AZposts as $AZpost) {
    $firstletter = strtoupper(substr($AZpost->post_title,0,1));
    if($firstletter != $current) {
        $postlist .= "<b><a name='$firstletter'> $firstletter </a></b><br>\n";
        $nav .= "<a href='#$firstletter'> $firstletter </a> ";
        $current = $firstletter;
    }
    $postlist .= $AZpost->post_title . "<br>\n";
}

print $nav . "<br>" . $postlist;
```

Comment: `get_permalink( $AZpost->ID )` would be probably useful. Besides that: Nice, canonical answer. +1 :)

Comment: @toscho how would someone get the permalinks to display as well?